# How to make ffmpeg to throw exception on try/catch for working directory and for arguments?

Tags: c#, winforms, ffmpeg

If for example i'm setting the FileName(outputDirectory) to null it will throw exception.

The class when i'm using process of the ffmpeg.exe :

```
public void Start()
        {
            process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.FileName = outputDirectory; // Change the directory where ffmpeg.exe is.  
            process.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
            process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory; // The output directory  
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true; //Redirect stdin
            process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            process.Start();

            errorMessage = false;
            startRecord = true;
        }
```

but if i'm setting the WorkingDirectory to null or entering some not valid Arguments like "sadasdasd" it will not throw exception not on the WorkingDirectory and not on the Arguments.

In Form1 :

```
private void recordStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            recordToggle = !recordToggle;

            if (recordToggle)
            {
                try
                {
                    record.workingDirectory = settingsForm.workingDirectory;
                    record.outputDirectory = settingsForm.outputDirectory;
                    record.arguments = settingsForm.arguments;
                    record.Start();
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    recordStripMenuItem.Text = "Record";
                    Icon = iconGreen;
                    TextInfo("Waiting");
                    recordToggle = false;
                    MessageBox.Show("Arguments are not valid : " + ex.Message);
                    
                }
                if (!FFmpeg_Capture.errorMessage)
                {
                    settingsForm.Close();
                    recordStripMenuItem.Text = "Stop";
                    Icon = iconRed;
                    TextInfo("Recording");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                recordStripMenuItem.Text = "Record";
                Icon = iconGreen;
                TextInfo("Waiting");
                record.Stop();
            }
        }
```

The variable record is instance of the FFmpeg_Capture class with the process of the ffmpeg.
It's throwing exception only on the FileName(outputDirectory).

Answer (score 1):

In your start() method add the following code that throws an exception if the working directory doesn't exist:

```
public void Start(){
    if(!System.IO.Directory.Exists(this.workingDirectory){
        throw new Exception("workingDirectory doesn't exist");
    }
    
    //.. the rest of the code
    
}
```

Comment: I think the important case is the arguments.  because in my winforms i did that you must enter a directory to the workingDirectory so i can handle it but how do i know if the user typed a valid arguments ? even if i'm typing in a textBox for example "adfasdasd" it's not throwing any exception/s on the arguments.

Comment: the exception will happen when the user starts the operation and it looks like you already handled all exceptions by showing the error message : `MessageBox.Show("Arguments are not valid : " + ex.Message);`. alternatively, if you want to validate what the user is typing in the textBox you should do the same logic inside some appropriate textBox event such as Leave

Comment: you right about that i added the line MessageBox.Show("Arguments are not valid : " + ex.Message); but when i'm adding to the arguments "asdfasdasd" it's not throwing any exceptions and never reaching the MessageBox.Show("Arguments are not valid : " + ex.Message);  it looks like there is no something in the Arguments that check for validation.  but for the outputDirectory it does.

Comment: you need to first specify exactly how the arguments string is supposed to look like in your application and then try using regular expression to validate and extract pieces of information from it.